# Problema com a estrutura condicional IF

Tags: python

Estou tentando aprender Python (e programação em geral). No momento, estou estudando if e else e condições and, or e not. Estou treinando fazendo um quiz sobre star wars, mas estou com uma dificuldade.

```
Score = 0

Resposta1 = input("No filme Star Wars, Episódio IV, Léia manda uma mensagem de socorro que diz: \n \" Help me ___________, "
         "you're my only hope.\" Para quem Léia estava pedindo ajuda?")

if Resposta1 == "Obi Wan Kenobi" or "Obi-Wan Kenobi" or "Obi Wan" or "obi wan":
    print("Boa, você é mesmo um Jedi!")
    Score = Score + 1
else:
  print("Você tem muito a aprender, jovem Padawn.")

print("Seu score atual é: " + str(Score))
```

O programa sabia distinguir entre uma resposta certa e uma errada antes deu adicionar outras grafias de Obi Wan com o "and". Agora, mesmo respostas erradas devolvem uma resposta positiva. Onde eu estou errando?

Comment: faz assim, if(Resposta1 == "texto" or Resposta1 == "texto2"...

Comment: Legal, isso resolveu! Tem alguma forma de usar o parenteses para não ter que repetir o nome da variável em todas as possíveis respostas?

Answer (score 6):

## Como o Python funciona

No `Python` uma `string` vazia em uma condição o retorno é falso, no entanto uma `string` com algum valor é retornando verdadeiro, veja um exemplo:

*Exemplo 1*

```
if "uma string qualquer" :
  print("Tudo ok")
else:
  print("Não deu")
```

*Exemplo 2*

**Resultado:** Tudo ok

```
if "" :
  print("Tudo ok")
else:
  print("Não deu")
```

**Resultado:** Não deu

## O problema

No seu caso, ele retornava falso na primeira condição `Resposta1 == "Obi Wan Kenobi"`, mas as outras strings estavam retornando verdadeiro, já que não eram vazias.

É necessário comparar a variável com todas as strings

```
if Resposta1 == "Obi Wan Kenobi" or Resposta1 == "Obi-Wan Kenobi" or Resposta1 == "Obi Wan" or Resposta1 == "obi wan":
```

Por isso que estava sempre retornando um valor positivo, veja o seu código editado:

```
Score = 0

Resposta1 = input("No filme Star Wars, Episódio IV, Léia manda uma mensagem de socorro que diz: \n \" Help me ___________, "
         "you're my only hope.\" Para quem Léia estava pedindo ajuda?")

if Resposta1 == "Obi Wan Kenobi" or Resposta1 == "Obi-Wan Kenobi" or Resposta1 == "Obi Wan" or Resposta1 == "obi wan":
    print("Boa, você é mesmo um Jedi!")
    Score = Score + 1
else:
  print("Você tem muito a aprender, jovem Padawn.")

print("Seu score atual é: " + str(Score))
```

## Código com melhorias

Para ficar mais fácil você pode usar o "in", exemplo:

```
if Resposta1 in ["Obi-Wan Kenobi", "Obi Wan", "obi wan"]:
```

O mesmo exemplo utilizando o seu código:

```
Score = 0

Resposta1 = input("""
No filme Star Wars, Episódio IV, Léia manda uma mensagem de socorro que diz:
Help me ___________, you're my only hope.\" Para quem Léia estava pedindo ajuda?
""")

if Resposta1 in ["Obi-Wan Kenobi", "Obi Wan", "obi wan"]:
    print("Boa, você é mesmo um Jedi!")
    Score = Score + 1
else:
  print("Você tem muito a aprender, jovem Padawn.")

print("Seu score atual é: " + str(Score))
```

> Desta forma ele verifica se a reposta se encontra no array, se sim,
>   ele retorna verdadeiro, aproveitei a dica do fernandosavio e utilizei
>   strings multilinhas para ficar mais fácil a leitura.

[Teste aqui](https://repl.it/repls/RepentantAptDiscussions)

Comment: Legal, isso resolveu! Tem alguma forma de usar o parenteses para não ter que repetir o nome da variável em todas as possíveis respostas?

Comment: vou fazer uma alteração e já posto

Comment: Você pode usar o "in", editei minha resposta utilizando

Comment: Você pode aproveitar e ensinar como usar strings multilinhas (`"""`) para não ter que adicionar os `\n` e o código ficar mais legível. ;)

Comment: Ah, então seria uma lista de respostas possíveis e o código checa se uma delas foi usada. Beleza, obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! Não se esqueça de avaliar positivamente a pergunta e marca como a reposta (y)

Comment: @fernandosavio, obrigado pela dica, já editei!

Comment: Agora tá bonito! :D Meu +1 já tinha ganhado hahah